Log postgres logs for only specific user
I am using postgres 15 and I have turned on the log_collector , log_destination, connection, disconnection, and log_statement = 'all'. Is there any way that I only generate logs in the destination log file if the user who he connected to database is specific (lets say john)? In fact I have many users and through current logging setup, not only my size of log files increases massively but also it is very inconvenient for me to use grep command and filter out the specific user logs.

You can control many settings via ALTER USER john SET ... and that includes statement logging. I don't think connection logging can be set like that because of course you aren't logged in at the start.

can you please provide the steps in a sequence or any article doing this stuff?
